# System.argumentoutofrangeexception while invoke Listviewitems using iterators

Tags: c#, asynchronous, iterator, listviewitem

I have an application which must contain the items in large quantities and continuously into listviews control:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        deg_loadfile load = new deg_loadfile(loadfile);
        load.BeginInvoke(new AsyncCallback(loadcallback),null);
    }

    void countfile() {

        int listcount = listView1.Items.Count;          
        for (int x = 0; x < listcount; x++) {

            listView1.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
                listView1.Items[x].SubItems[1].Text = "ok";
                listView1.Items[x].SubItems[2].Text = "ok";
                listView1.Items[x].SubItems[3].Text = "done";
            },x); 

        }

    }
    void countcallback(IAsyncResult ae) {
        MessageBox.Show("count finished");

    }
    delegate void deg_count();

    void loadcallback(IAsyncResult ae) {
        MessageBox.Show("finished");

    }
    delegate void deg_loadfile();
    void loadfile() {

        string file = File.ReadAllText("hughlist.txt");
        string[] files = Regex.Split(file,"\n");

        foreach (string str in files) {
            listView1.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
                ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(str);
                item.SubItems.Add("");
                item.SubItems.Add("");
                item.SubItems.Add("");
                listView1.Items.Add(item);                
            },str);          
        } 
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        deg_count count = new deg_count(countfile);
        count.BeginInvoke(new AsyncCallback(countcallback),null);

    }
```

The code above throws system.argumentoutofrangeexception (please see image below)

link image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJ7sA.png

The iteration has exceeded the conditions that I have given, why did it happen (note:in my  case, i must use "for" instead of "foreach" or other enumeration) ?

thx

**UPDATE:**
thx to @saruman for the answer (keyword is "access to modified closure"), i've updated the code as below

```
for (int x = 0; x < listcount; x++) {
            var x1=x;
            listView1.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                listView1.Items[x1].SubItems[1].Text = "ok";
                listView1.Items[x1].SubItems[2].Text = "ok";
                listView1.Items[x1].SubItems[3].Text = "done";
            }, x1); }
```

Comment: Does the loop execute at least once?

Comment: @l19 yes, it executes one time then throws the exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look up access to modified closure

Try this

```
var listcount = listView1.Items.Count;
for (var x = 0; x < listcount; x++)
{
   var x1 = x;
   listView1.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
   {
      listView1.Items[x1].SubItems[1].Text = "ok";
      listView1.Items[x1].SubItems[2].Text = "ok";
      listView1.Items[x1].SubItems[3].Text = "done";
   });
}
```

Comment: in my case, i cannot use "foreach",my app code only call loop once then jump to the limit.